# Fatal Error: Unable to find package java.lang in classpath or bootclasspath

Tags: java, netbeans, ubuntu-18.04, netbeans-10

Anyone who know why this is happening. I installed Netbeans on ubuntu 18.04 but when I create application it shows the errors as shown in the picture below
[Netbeans cannot read Java packages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JyBLc.png)